# Manipulate values of rows in a dataframe according to other rows with same group id

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with some `group_id`s, `value`s and `size`s such as this:

| group_id | value | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 1 |
| 0 | 10 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | 6 | 4 |

Rows with the same `group_id` also have the same `value`.

I would like to "distribute" the value of entries within the same group according to size. So for example the first row should be updated to have value = 10 * 1  / (1 + 3) = 2.5, while the second row should be updated to have value = 10 * 3 / (1+3) = 7.5, and the rest of the entries should not change (since there are no other rows in its group).

I tried iterating over the groups with the same `group_id` using a groupby construct, but from there I am a bit lost. I guess that if I could get the index of the rows withing a group I could slice the original dataframe and manipulate each group in turn. But I don't know how to do that nor if it is the most pythonic way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the value and size then divide with `groupby.transform` on the size column:

```
df['value'].mul(df['size']).div(df.groupby("group_id")['size'].transform('sum'))
```

---

```
0    2.5
1    7.5
2    5.0
3    6.0
dtype: float64
```

Assign this to a new column or replace an existing one as per your requirement